# CodeIgniter send mail from Ubuntu server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ubuntu, sendmail

when I'm sending mails from my local installation (Mac OSX), there is no problems with sending mails.

I have now uploaded my CodeIgniter project to the host Linode where i have an Ubuntu server installed. But now I'm no longer able to send mails. I have installed Postfix for sendmail, but it keeps saying:

```
Return-Path: <do_not_reply@XXX.com>
X-Original-To: XXX@XXX.com
Delivered-To: XXX@XXX.com
Received: by XXX.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id B332327FE9; Thu, 17 Dec 2015 11:41:32 +0100 (CET)
To: XXX@XXX.com
Subject: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:Email.php
User-Agent: PHPMailer
Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 11:41:32 +0100
From: "XXXX" <XXX@XXX.com>
Reply-To: "XXX@XXX.com" <XXX@XXX.com>
X-Sender: XXX@XXX.com
X-Mailer: PHPMailer
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5672915cb1605@XXX.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="B_ATC_5672915cb168a"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ATC_5672915cb168a
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5672915cb164d"

--B_ALT_5672915cb164d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Can anyone pls. explain me what I'm doing wrong?
The PHP code for sending mails is just standard.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it was blocked by Microsoft